# how to order the dataframe in a list

Tags: r

Sorry for a silly question. I have a lst `lbsl_lst`  which contain multiple df.  I would like to rearrange the order of df appear in the lst as :
JP002A-0002, JP002A-0003, JP007A-0001, JP002A-0001. what should I do in order to achieve this so lbsl_lst[[3]] will be JP007A-0001?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is this because you want to process the data frames in order? In which case it may be easier to use a vector with the ordered list names, no need to reorder the list itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a programmable logic to the order of names, but you could reorder based on their current indices:

```
lbsl_lst = lbsl_lst[c(2, 3, 4, 1)]
```

Or based on their names:

```
lbsl_lst = lbsl_lst[c("JP002A-0002", "JP002A-0003", "JP007A-0001", "JP002A-0001")]
```